# NoMethodError: undefined method 'clients' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I've run into the infamous NoMethodError which I can't seem to crack, even after browsing the number of SO posts.

**Note:** I am running on Cloud9 development environment

I'm making a productivity website where a user can have their clients, projects, etc.

I'm attempting to run the *clients_display_test.rb* test and am receiving the following terminal error.

Any help would be appreciated but I would ask, if you determine where my mistake is, *please specify where my lack of technical understanding was* :)

```
  1) Error:
ClientsDisplayTestTest#test_profile_display:
NoMethodError: undefined method `clients' for nil:NilClass
    app/controllers/clients_controller.rb:4:in `index'
    test/integration/clients_display_test_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:ClientsDisplayTestTest>'

48 runs, 127 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

*clients_display_test.rb*

```
require 'test_helper'

class ClientsDisplayTestTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include ApplicationHelper

  def setup
    @user = users(:Robert)
  end 

  test "profile display" do
    get '/clients'
    assert_template "clients/index"
    assert_select 'title', "Clients"
  end
end
```

Attached is some .rb files which hopefully could help:

*clients_controller.rb*

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @clients = current_user.clients.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end

    def show
    end
end
```

*routes.rb*

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'password_resets/newedit'

  root              'static_pages#home'
  get 'about' =>    'static_pages#about'
  get 'signup' =>   'users#new'

  get 'login' =>    'sessions#new'
  #the page for new session
  post 'login' =>   'sessions#create'
  #creates a new session
  delete 'logout' =>'sessions#destroy'
  #deletes the session
  get '/clients' => 'clients#index'
  get '/clients/show' => 'clients#show'

  resources :users
  resources :clients 
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
end
```

**Client Views:**

*index.html.erb*

```
    <%= provide(:title, 'Clients') %>

<div class="clients-container container"> 
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Add pagination later for multiple folders over multiple pages --> 
    <% if current_user.clients.any? %>
        <%= render @clients %> 
        <%= will_paginate @clients %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

*_client.html.erb*

```
<div class="col-md-2 client-folder" style="margin: 10px" id="client - <%= client.id %>">
  <span class="clientName" ><%= client.client_name %></span> <br>
  <span class="contactName"><%= client.contact_name %></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using Devise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your current_user is nil. You have to sign in your user in the test before visiting the page, otherwise the current_user method will return nil.

If you're using Devise for authentication then there are test helpers available, more about it here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec)